# smoothing of auto-correlated time series data with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

Is there a way to incorporate smoothing function for an auto-correlated time series in ggplot2?

I have time series data that is auto-correlated for which I currently use a manual process to determine 95% CI for the fitted spline.

Usage and Date are in a data frame AB. The main components of the model I use are as follows:

```
    d<-AB$Date
    a<-AB$Usage

    o<-order(d)
    d<-d[o]
    a<-a[o]

    id<-ts(1:length(d))
    a1<-ts(a)

    a2<-lag(a1-1)
    tg<-ts.union(a1,id,a2)
    mg<-lm(a1~a2+bs(id,df=df1), data=tg)
```

From this model I obtain fitted means and standard errors of the fit which are used to work out the 95% CI for the fitted spline.

I have seen examples of the lm method in ggplot2 with a term to specify the model formula. 
Is this kind of time series model achievable when the time series is auto-correlated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The CI will be biased if you use the simple formula in **ggplot2** for adding any model fit if there is dependence in the residuals.

If I were doing this, I would fit whatever model I wanted *outside* of **gpplot2**. Then predict from that model over a grid evenly spaced points in the range of the covariates. Compute confidence intervals for those predictions and combine these and the fitted values and the data into a single data frame. From there you can use `geom_line()` and `geom_ribbon()` for the fitted model and confidence interval respectively. This allows you to compute proper confidence intervals that account for the lack of independence in the residuals.

One issue I foresee is that you have a model that includes two covariates, whereas `ggplot()` would normally consider the relationship between a response and a single covariate. For example, if you are plotting `a1` vs `id` in ggplot but the model is for `a2 + bs(id)` then you'd need to account `a2` in some manner first, say be predicting for a range of values in `id` but keep `a2` fixed at some reasonable value, say the sample mean.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "account for the lack of *independence* in the residuals"?

Comment: @James Well spotted. I think I was in two minds as whether to say "account for the lack of independence", or "account for the dependence" and got myself muddled-up. Corrected now.

Comment: Thanks, figured as much. I ended up calulating confidence intervals and up/lower control limits and put them all in a data frame. Thanks @Gavin for the tip about `geom_ribbon()`.